# Odoo 14 - Override method associated with "Discard" button

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14

I need to run additional commands after the *Discard* button has been pressed.

I know how to do this with *Save* button:

```py
@api.model
def create(self, vals): 
    # my code before create
    result = super(MODEL_NAME, self).create(vals)
    # my code after create
    return result
```

But I'm unable to find method associated with "Discard" button. How is it called?

Comment: It's behind javascript code and not that easy to change.